# Gradle how to create an empty fileCollection?

Tags: file, gradle, collections, classpath

```
def mergedCompileClasspath == null
project.sourceSets.each {
        if (mergedCompileClasspath == null)
            mergedCompileClasspath = it.compileClasspath
        else    
            mergedCompileClasspath .plus(it.compileClasspath)

}
```

The plus() method is not working. compileClassPath is immutable? How to create an empty fileCollection?

Answer (score 12):

You can call [`Project.files()`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:files(java.lang.Object[])) with an empty collection.

```
def emptyFileCollection = project.files([])
```

**Update:**

As of Gradle 5.3 you can also use the [`ObjectFactory.fileCollection()`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/model/ObjectFactory.html#fileCollection--) method.

```
def emptyFileCollection = project.objects.fileCollection()
```

Comment: files([]), but FileCollection.plus(): returns java.util.ArryList. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63518070/gradle-filecollection-plus-returns-arraylist-contradicting-interface