# gradle: fileCollection.plus() returns ArrayList contradicting interface

Tags: java, gradle

gradle: fileCollection.plus() returns ArrayList contradicting interface.

```
def foo = files([]);  // foo: gradle FileCollection
println foo.class
foo = foo.plus(sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs);    // foo: java.util.ArrayList
println foo.class
```

But it should return a FileCollection:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileCollection.html#plus-org.gradle.api.file.FileCollection-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `plus` method is overloaded, and you are looking at the wrong one.

The API for [FileCollection.plus](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileCollection.html#plus-org.gradle.api.file.FileCollection-) that you linked to has the signature:

> **FileCollection plus​(FileCollection collection)**
>
> Returns a FileCollection which contains the union of this collection and the given collection. The returned collection is live, and tracks changes to both source collections.

But you are passing an `ArrayList` as the parameter. An `ArrayList` is not a `FileCollection`.

However, a `FileCollection` is also an `Iterable`, so what you are really invoking is the standard Groovy method [Interable.plus](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#plus(java.lang.Iterable)) with this signature:

> **public Collection plus(Iterable right)**
>
> Create a Collection as a union of two iterables. If the left iterable is a Set, then the returned collection will be a Set otherwise a List. This operation will always create a new object for the result, while the operands remain unchanged.

Because the "left" iterable is not a `Set` (it's a `FileCollection`), you get a `List` back, and Groovy just happens to use an `ArrayList` in the implementation.